# bootstrap navbar not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and found myself very quickly in trouble. 
first I want to mention that I got all the code from getbootstrap, with copy and paste, and tuned it to my needs.
So first of all I got the links and meta data (including the link to the latest bootstrap 4, the alpha version). then I used a code snipet from getbootstrap that implements a nav bar. I changed what I needed, and use it all my html documents.

Now, it allways works on the home page, but on the other 6 pages it rarely does. I know this sounds strange, but yes, usualy the nav-bar does not apear at all on the other pages, but some times it apears on contact page for example, later on it might disapear again from the contact page but apear on faq page, and without anyone messing with the code. mabey it's a good ideea to get an older but more stable version of bootstrap?

here is the code of the index.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ro">
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css
integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">


    </head>


    <body>

        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>


          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="servicii.html">Servicii</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="dotari.html">Dotari</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="preturi.html">Preturi</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="testimoniale.html">Testimoniale</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="faq.html">Intrebari frecvente</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="locatie.html">Locatie</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And now, here is the code to one of the other pages, I think 1 is enough since they are about the same thing, so I don't make you read 7 pages of code for nothing. at the moment I don't have any css or js files since I am using bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>



      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>




      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="servicii.html">Servicii</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="dotari.html">Dotari</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="preturi.html">Preturi</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="testimoniale.html">Testimoniale</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="faq.html">Intrebari frecvente</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="locatie.html">Locatie</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read this before posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your code and write the problem you are facing. We can help you after that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out by myself.

first of all, I stated that I used the alpha version of bootstrap 4. I was wrong, it's the beta version.

now, the answer!
the code works just fine, and that was the source of frustration, because I was looking again and again in to a code that I knew it was corect, but somehow it didn't work.
it was actualy a ftp error, for some reason, when I uploaded the files to the server, the nav on the other pages were not uploaded, so of corse the browser didn't show the nav, because on the server there was no nav to show.